# Why does this reactive event fail to render in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I do not understand why the code in this flexdashboard relative to 'Chart C' renders nothing while 'Chart B' code works fine.  Obviously there is an issue that is causing this problem. If there is a more efficient means of accomplishing the same task, I am all ears.  Could someone please assist?

This is a screenshot of the output.

[image]

````
    ---
    title: "untitled"
    output:
     flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
       orientation: rows
      
        
    runtime: shiny
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
     
     
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(
       echo    = FALSE,
       message = FALSE,
       warning = FALSE
    )
     
     
    library(shiny)
    library(flexdashboard)
     
     
     
    ```
     
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
     
    ```{r}
     
    # Chart A - UI
    
    user_choices <- 1:4       
    
    shiny::selectInput(
                inputId = "data",
                label   = c("Make a selection (1-4)"),
                choices = user_choices,
                selected = "3"                             
      )
     
     
     
    ```
     
     
    
    
    
    
    ```{r}
    
    # Chart B
    
             x1 <- eventReactive(input$data, 
                                 { as.numeric(input$data) }
                                 )
             
             
    renderPrint({
      
      list(
      
      x1(),
      
      x1() == 1,
      
      x1() == 2,
      
      x1() == 3,
      
      x1() == 4
      
     
      )
      
    
      
    })
    
    
    ```
    
    
    
    ```{r}
    
    #  Chart C
    
    
    renderPrint({
      
    
      x1 <- eventReactive( input$data, {
       
     
           if ( x1() == 1) {
                baby <- 12
         } else if ( x1() == 2) {
                baby <- 13
         }  else if ( x1() == 3) {
                baby <- 15
         }    else   {
                baby <- 22
         }
       
       baby
    
       })
    
     })
````

Comment: Have you tried moving the assignment of x1 outside of the renderPrint brackets, like in chart B?

Comment: Hi jp,  Doing that and leaving just baby inside renderPrint yields this error, "object 'baby' not found."   I could use something along the lines of c(12, 13, 15, 22)[as.numeric(input$baby)]; however, my actual code has much more code within the if statements.  Thus, I am seeking a solution that maintains the if statements.  Oddly, when I moved the eventReactive statement outside  renderPrint, my Chart B failed and received this error, "C stack usage  7970672 is too close to the limit."